# Header only HTTP client library that is a wrapper around CURL

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

For learning purposes, I wanted to create a header-only C++ wrapper library around HTTP CURL functionality. At the moment the library only implements GET and POST, but I will add other HTTP methods later. Additionally, right now it only supports calling `get()` or `post()` with a fully constructed `RequestConfig` object. I plan on adding overloads that allow the user to pass only some of the parameters (URL, URL & parameters, etc).

Any pointers or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

**httplib.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <iterator> 
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

namespace easyhttp {

    enum class HttpRequestType { get, post };
    enum class RequestError { none, timeout, socket_error, error_misc };

    struct BasicAuthentication {
        std::string username;
        std::string password;
    };

    struct HttpResponse {
        RequestError error;
        std::string response_code;
        std::string content;
    };

    class Parameters {

    public:

        using iterator = std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator;

        Parameters() {}

        explicit Parameters(const std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>& list) {
            for (auto itr = list.begin(); itr != list.end(); itr++) {
                if (!itr->first.empty()) {
                    items_[itr->first] = itr->second;
                }
            }
        }

        explicit Parameters(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& x) {
            items_[x.first] = x.second;
        }

        explicit Parameters(const std::map<std::string, std::string> x) : items_{ x } {}

        void add(std::pair<std::string, std::string> p) {
            if (!p.first.empty()) {
                items_[p.first] = p.second;
            }
        }

        void remove(std::string key) {
            items_.erase(key);
        }

        size_t size() {
            return items_.size();
        }

        std::string get_value(std::string key) {
            return (items_.find(key) == items_.end()) ? "" : items_[key];
        }

        void clear() {
            items_.clear();
        }

        std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator begin() {
            return items_.begin();
        }

        std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator end() {
            return items_.end();
        }

    protected:
        std::map<std::string, std::string> items_;
    };


    class UrlParameters : public Parameters {
    public:

        UrlParameters() : Parameters() {}

        explicit UrlParameters(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> list)
            : Parameters(list) {}

        explicit UrlParameters(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& x)
            : Parameters(x) {}

        explicit UrlParameters(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& x)
            : Parameters(x) {}

        std::string get_string() {
            if (str_.empty()) {
                encode();
                return str_;
            }

            return str_;
        }
        std::string get_encoded_string() {
            if (encoded_str_.empty()) {
                return encode();
            }

            return encoded_str_;
        }

        std::string encode() {

            if (items_.size() == 0) {
                return "";
            }

            str_.clear();
            encoded_str_.clear();

            str_ = "?";
            encoded_str_ = "?";

            for (auto& [k, v] : items_) {
                str_ += ("&" + k + "=" + v);
                encoded_str_ += ("&" + url_escape_str(std::string(k)) + "=" + url_escape_str(std::string(v)));
            }

            str_.erase(1, 1);
            encoded_str_.erase(1, 1);

            return encoded_str_;
        }

    private:

        std::string url_escape_str(std::string& orig) {

            // Think about a possible try catch here
            // Technically, std::strings ctor can throw
            char *res = curl_easy_escape(nullptr, orig.c_str(), orig.length());

            std::string escaped_str = std::string(res);
            curl_free(res);
            return escaped_str;
        }

        std::string str_;
        std::string encoded_str_;

    };

    class Headers : public Parameters {
    public:

        Headers() : Parameters() {}

        explicit Headers(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> list)
            : Parameters(list) {}

        explicit Headers(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& x)
            : Parameters(x) {}

        explicit Headers(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& x)
            : Parameters(x) {}

        std::string encode(const std::string key) {
            return (items_.find(key) == items_.end()) ? "" : key + ": " + items_[key];
        }

    };

    struct RequestConfig {
        std::string url;
        UrlParameters params;
        Headers headers;
        BasicAuthentication auth;
        std::chrono::seconds timeout_sec;
    };

    namespace{

        size_t http_request_impl_response_write(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t numb, void* ud) {
            size_t response_size = size * numb;
            std::stringstream* ss = (std::stringstream*)ud;
            ss->write(ptr, response_size);
            return response_size;
        }
    }

    class Request {
    public:

        HttpResponse post(RequestConfig& c) {
            HttpResponse resp = http_request_impl(HttpRequestType::post, c);
            return resp;
        }

        HttpResponse get(RequestConfig& c) {
            HttpResponse resp = http_request_impl(HttpRequestType::get, c);
            return resp;
        }

    private:

        HttpResponse http_request_impl(const HttpRequestType r, RequestConfig& c) {

            CURL* curl;
            struct curl_slist* chunk = NULL;
            curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
            curl = curl_easy_init();

            std::stringstream response_stream;
            HttpResponse resp;

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, static_cast<long>(c.timeout_sec.count()));
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, (c.url + c.params.get_encoded_string()).c_str());

            if (c.headers.size() > 0) {
                for (const auto& [k,v] : c.headers) {
                    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, c.headers.encode(k).c_str());
                }

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
            }

            if (r == HttpRequestType::post) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

                if (c.params.size() > 0) {
                    std::string temp = c.params.get_encoded_string();
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, temp.c_str());
                }

                else {
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
                }
            }

            if (!c.auth.username.empty() && !c.auth.password.empty()) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, c.auth.username.c_str());
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, c.auth.password.c_str());
            }

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, http_request_impl_response_write);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response_stream);

            CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            auto http_code = 0L;
            curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            curl_slist_free_all(chunk);

            if (res == CURLE_OK) {
                resp.content = response_stream.str();
                resp.error = RequestError::none;
                resp.response_code = std::to_string(http_code);
            }

            else if (res == CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT) {
                resp.content = "Operation timed out.";
                resp.error = RequestError::timeout;
                resp.response_code = "-1";
            }

            else {
                resp.content = "Request encountered error: " + std::string(curl_easy_strerror(res));
                resp.error = RequestError::error_misc;
                resp.response_code = "-1";
            }

            return resp;

        }

    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a bit of code to look at. This is not a complete review, but I did two simple things, which may prompt thought / improvements:

1. I ran a static analyser over your code (clang-tidy V9). The output is below. It is pointing many of the stylistic things I would say too. And it highlights some actual issues.
2. I added a `main()` method and i tried to use your code. ie, I made it "work". This also highlighted a couple of small issues. Try it yourself. Is this the API you want for the users of your library? How could it be improved?

my `main()`:

```
int main()
{
  auto req_params = easyhttp::UrlParameters{{"q","test"}};
  auto req_config = easyhttp::RequestConfig{
    "https://www.google.com",
    req_params,
    {},
    {},
    std::chrono::duration<long>{10}
  };
  auto req = easyhttp::Request();
  auto response = req.get(req_config);
  std::cout << response.content << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

clang-tidy output

```
curl2.cpp:18:8: warning: constructor does not initialize these fields: error [hicpp-member-init]
struct HttpResponse {
       ^
curl2.cpp:29:3: warning: use '= default' to define a trivial default constructor [hicpp-use-equals-default]
  Parameters() {}
  ^            ~~
               = default;
curl2.cpp:31:12: warning: initializer-list constructor should not be declared explicit [google-explicit-constructor]
  explicit Parameters(const std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>& list) {
  ~~~~~~~~~^
curl2.cpp:32:5: warning: use range-based for loop instead [modernize-loop-convert]
    for (auto itr = list.begin(); itr != list.end(); itr++) {
    ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        (const auto & itr : list)
curl2.cpp:41:64: warning: the const qualified parameter 'x' is copied for each invocation; consider making it a reference [performance-unnecessary-value-param]
  explicit Parameters(const std::map<std::string, std::string> x) : items_{x} {}
                                                               ^
                                                              &
curl2.cpp:43:48: warning: the parameter 'p' is copied for each invocation but only used as a const reference; consider making it a const reference [performance-unnecessary-value-param]
  void add(std::pair<std::string, std::string> p) {
                                               ^
           const                              &
curl2.cpp:49:27: warning: the parameter 'key' is copied for each invocation but only used as a const reference; consider making it a const reference [performance-unnecessary-value-param]
  void remove(std::string key) { items_.erase(key); }
                          ^
              const      &
curl2.cpp:53:37: warning: the parameter 'key' is copied for each invocation but only used as a const reference; consider making it a const reference [performance-unnecessary-value-param]
  std::string get_value(std::string key) {
                                    ^
                        const      &
curl2.cpp:64:38: warning: member variable 'items_' has protected visibility [cppcoreguidelines-non-private-member-variables-in-classes]
  std::map<std::string, std::string> items_;
                                     ^
curl2.cpp:69:21: warning: initializer for base class 'easyhttp::Parameters' is redundant [readability-redundant-member-init]
  UrlParameters() : Parameters() {}
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
curl2.cpp:71:12: warning: initializer-list constructor should not be declared explicit [google-explicit-constructor]
  explicit UrlParameters(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> list)
  ~~~~~~~~~^
curl2.cpp:96:9: warning: the 'empty' method should be used to check for emptiness instead of 'size' [readability-container-size-empty]
    if (items_.size() == 0) {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        items_.empty()
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:463:7: note: method 'map'::empty() defined here
      empty() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      ^
curl2.cpp:107:30: warning: string concatenation results in allocation of unnecessary temporary strings; consider using 'operator+=' or 'string::append()' instead [performance-inefficient-string-concatenation]
      str_ += ("&" + k + "=" + v);
                             ^
curl2.cpp:118:15: warning: method 'url_escape_str' can be made static [readability-convert-member-functions-to-static]
  std::string url_escape_str(const std::string& orig) {
              ^
  static
curl2.cpp:135:15: warning: initializer for base class 'easyhttp::Parameters' is redundant [readability-redundant-member-init]
  Headers() : Parameters() {}
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
curl2.cpp:137:12: warning: initializer-list constructor should not be declared explicit [google-explicit-constructor]
  explicit Headers(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> list)
  ~~~~~~~~~^
curl2.cpp:144:40: warning: the const qualified parameter 'key' is copied for each invocation; consider making it a reference [performance-unnecessary-value-param]
  std::string encode(const std::string key) {
                                       ^
                                      &
curl2.cpp:161:3: warning: use auto when initializing with a cast to avoid duplicating the type name [hicpp-use-auto]
  std::stringstream* ss            = (std::stringstream*)ud;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  auto
curl2.cpp:161:38: warning: C-style casts are discouraged; use static_cast [google-readability-casting]
  std::stringstream* ss            = (std::stringstream*)ud;
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     static_cast<std::stringstream*>( )
curl2.cpp:161:38: warning: do not use C-style cast to convert between unrelated types [cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-cstyle-cast]
curl2.cpp:180:16: warning: method 'http_request_impl' can be made static [readability-convert-member-functions-to-static]
  HttpResponse http_request_impl(const HttpRequestType r, RequestConfig& c) {
               ^
  static
curl2.cpp:183:32: warning: use nullptr [modernize-use-nullptr]
    struct curl_slist* chunk = NULL;
                               ^~~~
                               nullptr
```